# Python 2.7, import xlrd error

Tags: python, import

This is what the src looks like....very simple to start:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
```

When I try running I get this error:

```
import xlrd
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\xlrd-1.0.0\xlrd\__init__.py", line 306, in <module>
    import sys, zipfile, pprint
File "C:\Python27\Lib\zipfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    import struct, os, time, sys, shutil
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 12, in <module>
    import collections
File "C:\Python27\Lib\collections.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
ImportError: cannot import name iskeyword
```

I can use the interactive console and its not an issue...!
Puzzled...I checked my path packages etc...they look correct but it looks like a path issue but why does it work in the interactive console?

Here is my current versions of eclipse and phydev:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112
PyDev for Eclipse   5.3.1.20161031131

Comment: Any chance you have named a file `keyword.py` and that shadows the `keyword` module in the standard library? What is printed before the traceback if you put `import keyword; print(keyword)` before the `import xlrd` line?

Comment: That's a great catch..I am going to remove that file (keyword.py)
..and see if that does the trick.

First need to upgrade and buy a new laptop (oldie but goodie) having issues with eclipse launching properly because of memory issues.

Thanks for your input!